# Why is there no scrollbar in my tableview in my popovercontroller?

Tags: ios, scrollbar, tableview, uipopovercontroller

I can't see a scrollbar in the tableview in my popoverController, as a result of which just few records are accessible.

codes in popovercontroller.m:

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover=CGSizeMake(200.0, 320.0);
popoverTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 320) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

//[popoverTableView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
//[popoverTableView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];

popoverTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
[popoverTableView setDataSource:self];
[popoverTableView setDelegate:self];

[[self view] addSubview:popoverTableView];  

}
```

then just few records will be accessible:
[image]

Comment: You have to be a lot more specific than that. I mean **a lot** more specific. For example, you could link an image (now that you have enough reputation for it, you should consider adding a picture to your question). You could perhaps add some code, too. Otherwise, it's very hard to make sense of your question, let alone answering it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight now i have linked an image and added some code, too. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: This is a lot better! I don't have a certain answer, but sometimes the scroll indicators would be there, but invisible because of clipping. I would try making the popover window wider, or the table a bit narrower to see if the scroll indicator would appear. Also `contentSizeForViewInPopover` sets the initial size of the popover; see if you could set `popoverContentSize` instead. Good luck!